# installation of 15.10 failed

Tags: system-installation, 15.10

I've run the ubuntu installation from an USB stick and starts well. But in the end, the install freezes and does not resume. The copy process runs,but it seems that the install finish with a internet update (that i did not want).
Grub is not installed, but for the next install process, the previous install was detected.

Does someone had the same problem and solved it ?

Comment: Unplug the internet let it be wifi or ethernet during the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be failing hard drives.

You can check this quickly by "trying Ubuntu" then look for "Disks" and it will tell you if the drive is "going to fail soon" you can also check if you can hear clicking from the hard drive as it's running.

Comment: Thanks for this anwser. The Disk utility does not detect my disk as "going to fail soon". I've aborted the installation on this disk and will try with another one.